# Can someone explain to me what this transition means here: a, Z : AZ

Tags: formal-languages, automata, pushdown-automata

[image]

Can someone explain to me what this transition means here: a, Z : AZ

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks context but from what I infer I think it means that whenever you're in a configuration such that you are reading $a$ and $Z$ is on top of the stack then you replace the top of the stack by $AZ$.

That is you have the following transition $(q_0,aw',Z\gamma) \vdash (q_0, w', AZ\gamma)$ for $w' \in \{a,b\}^*$ and $\gamma \in \{A,Z\}^*$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was expecting an arrow before AZ. Do you by any chance know how to convert a PDA into a CFG. I don‘t know how to convert the transitions for the formal definition.

Comment: Ok! Did this answer your question? If so mark as accepted.
Regarding your other question, I know it but I could not easily describe it to you in this comment section. For that maybe check Sipser's book or maybe Aho,Ullman or any other textbook. It's a quite standard theorem in formal languages theory.